# install4j how to specify install dir on Windows Gradle

Tags: gradle, install4j

I have trouble using install4j on Windows for the project tripleA.

See source at: https://github.com/gaborbernat/triplea/blob/installer/build.gradle

I'm using the Gradle Plugin however I'm unable to specify the install 4j home directory.

If I try using absolute path that is 'C:/Program Files/install4j6' i get a normalization error as it gets translated  to:

"C:/data/tripleA/'C:/Program Files/install4j6'"

what am I missing here? why is file('C:/Program Files/install4j6') referring to "C:/data/tripleA/'C:/Program Files/install4j6'"?

Now if I use a relative path it says the folder does not exists.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to your build.gradle, the path is retrieved from properties file. It seems, that this path in your properties is placed within single quotes, as `'C:/Program Files/install4j6'`, and your gradle script logic get the value with this quotes.

That is the reason, `file()` doesn't recognize it as absolute path and tries to parse it as relative. Here is some code, which reproduces your exception:

```
task testFile {
    File ff = file('\'d:/test.xml\'')
    println ff.absolutePath
}
```

This will cause an error

> Could not normalize path for file 'D:\path\to\your\project\'d:\test.xml''

So, you should try to change the property, to make it a plain string without quotes.